# C programming: printing a null-terminated string using a character pointer

Tags: arrays, c, char

I am just getting used to pointers in C. I was thinking of using %s to print the first character of a character array.

In the following code, why does %s not work, but %c works? If *my_string is dereferencing the first value of the character array, wouldn't %s try to print all the characters in memory starting at that address and continue until a null-zero character is reached?

Also, how is `printf("%s", my_string)` working, but `printf("%s" *my_string)` is not?

```
char* my_string = "The original value.";
printf("Value of my_string: %s\n", my_string);
my_string = "The new value.";
printf("Value of my_string: %s\n", *my_string); // Error
printf("Value of my_string: %c\n", *my_string); // Prints only the first letter 'T', but does not have any errors
```

Comment: `%s` expects a null terminated string, `*my_string` is not a pointer, it is a `char` value, and `%s` tries to use that value as a pointer, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: " If *my_string is dereferencing the first value" It is. Meaning it goes to the address and fetch the contents there. "wouldn't %s try to print all the characters in memory starting at that address" But `my_string` is the address, `*my_string` is the contents of that address. `%s` expects the former, not the latter.

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk `*` de-references the pointer to the type that it is pointing to, so when `my_string` is a pointer to a character, `*my_string` is a character. Your C compiler sees your format string containing a `%s` and a parameter of `*my_string` which is a character and shows you an error.

To output the whole string, print it as in your first call to `printf`, to print only a single character do as you did in your last call to `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

To understand this we need to go into how the string `"The original value."` is stored in the memory and what the `char* my_string` points to.

We can expect a memory structure like this

```
0xDEADBEEF    ASCII T
0xDEADBEEF+1  ASCII h
0xDEADBEEF+2  ASCII e
0xDEADBEEF+3  ASCII <space>
...
0xDEADBEEF+16 ASCII u
0xDEADBEEF+17 ASCII e
0xDEADBEEF+18 ASCII .
0xDEADBEEF+19       0
```

So when you have a `char* my_string` it points to the first character or in this case the address `0xDEADBEEF`. So when you use `%s` in a `printf` it will loop through all the characters starting from the first one you pointed to until it reaches `\0`. But `*my_string` just reads the first character on that address. For that reason we need to give it a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> why does %s not work, but %c works?

It is the rule by which how the printf function works. For "%s" it expects a pointer to a null ending string, and for "%c" it expects a single character.

> If *my_string is dereferencing the first value of the character array, wouldn't %s try to print all the characters in memory starting at that address and continue until a null-zero character is reached?

Yes. So you must be careful in case it is a string too long and these characters are printable before the null ending.

> Also, how is printf("%s", my_string) working, but printf("%s" *my_string) is not?

For "%s", it expects a pointer. "*my_string" is a character.

Comment: Good first answer.